# Jquery code to get data from http

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to know what can I do to show a list into a html page using jquery.html and $getJson,
I have a server.js running on http:localhost:8080/list and I want to show the list between html tags

the html code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="http://jquery.com/">jQuery</a>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>

 $.get( "http://localhost:8080/clubs", myCallBack );
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `myCallBack` is where you define a function which can take the data as a parameter.

```
$.get("http://localhost:8080/clubs", function (data) {
    $("#myDiv").html(data);
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

---

The [jQuery Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) for `jQuery.get()` includes the following example:

```
$.get("ajax/test.html", function(data) {
  $(".result").html(data);
  alert("Load was performed.");
});
```